How to integrate Helia with a provider (such as infura or web3-storage)
I am new to IPFS and am trying to pin my data through helia with a provider(Infura or web3-storage). I have followed the  Helia-101.
At first, I thought I would be able to pin the text by running the example files, especially "301-networking.js". However, I realized that I need either a locally running node or a provider's running node to achieve this.
So, I decided to use a provider such as Infura or Web3.Storage.
The only solution I found involves using ipfs-http-client, but it is deprecated:
However, the problem is that there is not much information available on integrating Helia with a provider.
import { create } from "ipfs-http-client";

const projectId = "";
const projectSecret = "";
const auth = "Basic " + btoa(`${projectId}:${projectSecret}`);

const ipfs = create({
  host: "ipfs.infura.io",
  port: 5001,
  protocol: "https",
  headers: {
    authorization: auth,
  },
});

So, I tried to do something similar, referencing the migration from js-ipfs
import { createHelia } from "helia";
import { unixfs } from "@helia/unixfs";
const projectId = "";
const projectSecret = "";
const auth =
  "Basic " + Buffer.from(`${projectId}:${projectSecret}`).toString("base64");

const helia = await createHelia({
  host: "ipfs.infura.io",
  port: 5001,
  protocol: "https",
  headers: {
    authorization: auth,
  },
});

However, this Helia node does not upload my data to the IPFS network.
I believe I probably need to configure Helia correctly to upload data to the IPFS network.
Could you please give me some advice?
